# Remembering First Value Read in From a File in Java

Tags: java, file

**Please Note:**
I created a post earlier that had this question along with several others, but was told that since I was asking so many questions in the same post, it'd be better to break it up into individual questions. So please do not mark this as a duplicate, yes the instructions are the same and yes the same code is being used, but the question itself is different. Thanks.

I'm working on a program with the following instructions:

Write a class named Octagon that extends GeometricObject and implements the Comparable and Cloneable interfaces. Assume that all 8 sides of the octagon are of equal size. The area can be computed using the following formula

```
area = (2 + 4/square root of 2) * side * side
```

Write a program (driver) to read in a series of values from a file, display the area and perimeter, create a clone and compare the object and its clone (based on the area). In addition, your program should compare the current object (just read in) with the first object read in. The program ends when a negative number is read from the file.

Here is the code I have so far, This is my GeometricObject Class:

```
public abstract class GeometricObject {

    public abstract double getArea();
    public abstract double getPerimeter(); 
}
```

My Octagon class:

```
public class Octagon extends GeometricObject implements Comparable<Octagon> {
    private double side = 1.0;
    protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
    private static int numberOfObjects = 0; 

    public Octagon() {
    }

    public Octagon(double side) {
        this.side = side;
        numberOfObjects++;
    }

    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(double side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return (2 + (4 / (Math.sqrt(2))) * side * side); 
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return side * 8;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Octagon " + numCreated + ": Area: " + getArea() + "\nPerimeter: " 
            + getPerimeter() + "\nClone Compare: " + Cloneable + "\nFirst Compare: "
            + comparisson;
    }

    public int compareTo(Octagon octagon) {
        if(getArea() > octagon.getArea()) 
            return 1;
        else if(getArea() < octagon.getArea()) 
                return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public interface Cloneable {
    } 
}
```

And my Driver or tester class: (This is where I need the most help)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int comparisson = compareTo(octagon);
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("prog7.dat");
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(file);

        while(fin.hasNext()) {
            double side = fin.nextDouble();
                if(side < 0.0) break;
            Octagon first = new Octagon(side);
            System.out.println("Octagon 1: " + first);

        }

    }
}
```

And here is the file being used to get the input. Each line is one octagon:

```
5.0
7.5
3.26
0.0
-1.0
```

Here are the issues I'm running into.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create the objects. The output is supposed to look something like this:

Object 1: Area: 120.71
          Perimeter: 40.0
          Clone Compare: Equal
          First Compare: Equal

Object 2: Area: 271.60
          Perimeter: 60.0
          Clone Compare: Equal
          First Compare: The first is smaller

So I'm trying to figure out how to create the objects in a way that the first one is stored in its own variable (since it will be used as a comparison for the rest of the objects), cloned, and compared to itself and have the correct information printed out, then create the next object based on the next number in the file, clone it, compare it to the first object, and print the information, and continue doing this until I reach a negative number in the file. I hope that made sense, I know what I'm thinking just not sure how to put it into words ha.

Comment: It looks like the code you've posted won't compile, although I haven't tried it. But `numCreated` is not declared in `Octagon` and what you have for `clone()` is problematic.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to take that out, it has been changed since I posted this and I need to update. I have no idea where to even start with the cloneable part :-/

Comment: You probably want to define `clone` as `@Override public Octagon clone() { return new Octagon(this.side); }` and add `, Cloneable` to the `implements` clause in your class declaration.

Comment: When I add Cloneable to the implements clause, do I need to write implements again, like ... implements ... implements Cloneable ? or just something like implements ... Cloneable?

Comment: Also, in what class would I need to do the Override? Sorry, still really new at this.

Comment: Never mind the first question, I see the comma now and assume that means I can do both with one implements statement

Comment: You would just write `implements Comparable<Octagon>, Cloneable`. You would do the override in the `Octagon` class. The `@Override` annotation goes immediately before the method you are overriding and tells the compiler that you intend to override some method from an interface or superclass. That way, if you didn't actually override a method (like, if you got the name wrong), the compiler can warn you of that.

Comment: I should say, if you got the name wrong, or the parameters, the types -- for whatever reason, it didn't really override a method. It can be really hard to find the problem when you think you're overriding a method but you're not, so having the compiler detect it is very useful.

Comment: Ok great thanks. Now I guess I just need to know how this would go into my toString() method to print the "Clone Compare" portion of the output?

Comment: I tried just adding "Clone Compare: " + clone() + ... but that gave me a massive StackOverflow error.

Comment: `clone()` is just going to give you another `Octagon` object. How you compare them, and what you print, is up to you, but it doesn't really have anything to do with your `toString()` method. I think this is really a different question, since this question was just about how to remember the first value read in.

Comment: Ok, I'll do another question. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep a reference to the first `Octagon`, there are two approaches you can try. You can either have a flag that indicates whether you've seen the first one yet:

```
Octagon first;
boolean seenFirst = false;

while (fin.hasNext()) {
   double side = fin.nextDouble();
   if (side < 0.0) break;
   Octagon octagon = new Octagon(side);
   if (!seenFirst) {
       first = octagon;
       seenFirst = true;
   }
   // ... do stuff with octagons
}
```

You can even use `first` to keep track of whether it's been set yet:

```
Octagon first = null;

while (fin.hasNext()) {
   double side = fin.nextDouble();
   if (side < 0.0) break;
   Octagon octagon = new Octagon(side);
   if (first == null) {
       first = octagon;
   }
   // ... do stuff with octagons
}
```

Or, you can take a different approach. Instead of having conditional code inside your while loop, you can read the first `Octagon` before the loop begins:

```
Octagon first;

if (fin.hasNext()) {
   double side = fin.nextDouble();
   if (side < 0.0) return; // return instead of break to exit from main()
   first = new Octagon(side);
   doStuffWithOctagons(first, first);
}

while (fin.hasNext()) {
   double side = fin.nextDouble();
   if (side < 0.0) break;
   Octagon octagon = new Octagon(side);
   doStuffWithOctagons(first, octagon);
}
```

I've made `doStuffWithOctagons` into a method that takes the first octagon and the current octagon so as not to duplicate the code that does the rest of the operations with octagons in two places. Note that for the first octagon, I'm passing `first` as **both** parameters to it. I'm not sure if you actually want to do that step of comparing the current octagon with the first octagon when you've just read in the first octagon. It seems redundant, since they will obviously compare equal, but I couldn't quite tell from your question if you did want to do that.

There was a time when I would have preferred the former code, with an `if` statement in the `while` loop to handle the first case differently. Now I would probably prefer the latter code as it is more clear and explicit, although longer.